# Make custom checkout fields appear as editable in Woocommerce admin order single pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I added fields to the WooCommerce Checkout field; Some with a plugin ( WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor and WooCommerce Checkout Add-Ons ) and others with a function.

I can export these fields to CSV, but How can I edit them in the order admin page? Sometimes I a user might forget to add their ClientCode or ID Number, and then I want to be able to manually add it.

Thank you
Schalk

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add existing custom checkout billing and shipping fields to the editable 
 order shipping and billing sections in edit order pages, you will use one or both of the following filter hooks:

- For editable admin order **"Billing"** section: `woocommerce_admin_billing_fields`,
- For editable admin order **"Shipping"** section: `woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields`.

**Example usage and related answers:**

- [Editable admin custom billing fields error issue in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164248/editable-admin-custom-billing-fields-error-issue-in-woocommerce-3/51164431#51164431)
- [Add a drop down list of cities on admin orders pages in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397761/add-a-drop-down-list-of-cities-on-admin-orders-pages-in-woocommerce/52398138#52398138)

Those fields values will be automatically saved when edited/changed.

---

For others very custom checkout fields you can add them out of the editable boxes at the bottom of each section using one of those actions hooks:

- At the bottom of "General" section: `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details`
- At the bottom of "Billing" section: `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address`
- At the bottom of "Shipping" section: `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address`

Then you will have to add similar editable fields, with the same keys *(name attribute)* and use `save_post_shop_order` action hook…